# Difference between a sliver and a chip

Tags: differences

What is the difference between **a sliver** and **a chip** in the meaning of **broken piece of something**?

Comment: When dictionary definitions conflict or are imprecise, and when questions of common usage arise, what else should a questioner include? Native speakers say _sliver_ and _chip_ in different contexts. I think it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [*sliver*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sliver?s=t) is small, narrow, and most likely sharp enough to penetrate the skin.

A [chip](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/chip) is any small piece broken off from something else without reference to shape or sharpness, though [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chip?s=t) seems to think chips are small and slender as well. Wood chips that come from a wood chipper or the wood chips you buy at a garden store are small but rarely narrow.

A chip can also be what it is and what it isn't: a glass or piece of crockery might have a chip, that is, a chip missing, but the missing chip is, obviously, also a chip.

Comment: And, of course, a gambling token is a *chip*.

Comment: @HotLicks: The OP asked only about meanings dealing with broken pieces, so no slivers of cake or poker, micro-, potato, or cow chips.